# Why does ${fh} behave differentially than $fh when reading line by line?

Tags: perl

This script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my ${fh};

open($fh, '<', "some_file.txt") or die "fail\n";

while(my $line = <${fh}> ) {
    print $line;
}
close $fh;
```

outputs:

```
GLOB(0x5bcc2a0)
```

Why is this the output?

If I change `<${fh}>` to `<$fh>`, it will print `some_file.txt` line by line as expected. I thought the braces could be used to delimit variable names, and that `my ${var}` would be the same as `my $var`.

Are there other scenarios where adding `{}` around a variable name causes problems?

I tried on Perl 5.8.8 on Red Hat and Cygwin Perl 5.14.

Comment: There are lots of scenarios where adding `{}` changes the parse, e.g. `"$foobar"` vs. `"${foo}bar"`, `"$foo::bar"` vs. `"${foo}::bar"`, `"$foo's bar"` vs. `"${foo}'s bar"`, `"$foo[0]"` vs. `"${foo}[0]"`. But I'm guessing you're asking about situations besides string interpolation?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot you guessed right. Great answer too!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the section on `<>` in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators):

> If what the angle brackets contain is a simple scalar variable (for example, `$foo`), then that variable contains the name of the filehandle to input from, or its typeglob, or a reference to the same. For example:
>
> ```
> $fh = \*STDIN;
> $line = <$fh>;
> ```
>
> If what's within the angle brackets is neither a filehandle nor a simple scalar variable containing a filehandle name, typeglob, or typeglob reference, it is interpreted as a filename pattern to be globbed, and either a list of filenames or the next filename in the list is returned, depending on context. This distinction is determined on syntactic grounds alone. That means `<$x>` is always a `readline()` from an indirect handle, but `<$hash{key}>` is always a `glob()`. That's because `$x` is a simple scalar variable, but `$hash{key}` is not--it's a hash element. Even `<$x >` (note the extra space) is treated as `glob("$x ")`, not `readline($x)`.

You can see this with [B::Concise](http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Concise.html):

```
$ perl -MO=Concise -e'<$fh>'
5  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC ->(end)
1     <0> enter ->2
2     <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{ ->3
4     <1> readline[t1] vK*/1 ->5
-        <1> ex-rv2sv sK/1 ->4
3           <$> gvsv(*fh) s ->4
-e syntax OK

$ perl -MO=Concise -e'<${fh}>'
6  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC ->(end)
1     <0> enter ->2
2     <;> nextstate(main 70 -e:1) v:{ ->3
5     <@> glob[t1] vK/1 ->6
-        <0> ex-pushmark s ->3
-        <1> ex-rv2sv sK/1 ->4
3           <$> gvsv(*fh) s ->4
4        <$> gv(*_GEN_0) s ->5
-e syntax OK
```

Answer (score 11):

- `<>` means `readline(ARGV)`
- `<IDENTIFIER>` means `readline(IDENTIFIER)`
- `<$IDENTIFIER>` means `readline($IDENTIFIER)`
- `<...>` (anything else) means `glob(qq<...>)`

So,

- `<$fh>` means `readline($fh)`
- `<${fh}>` means `glob(qq<${fh}>)`, which is the same as `glob("$fh")`.

[`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) is used to generate a number of strings or file names from a pattern.

In this case, the stringification of the file handle is `GLOB(0x5bcc2a0)`. This is being passed to glob, but none of those characters have a special meaning for `glob`, so `glob` simply returns that string.

Comment: So basically `<>` is defined at the utter character level ... wow, CS flunk job!

Comment: @Kaz, Where did you get that? My post defined it in terms of tokens. Even if it did use a sub-language (like `m//`, `tr///`, `sprintf` and `glob` do), I don't see why that gets your knickers in a knot.

Comment: In the other answer it is noted (quoted from documentation) that even `<$x >` is completely different from `<$x>`.

Comment: @Kaz, In this answer too. So what? Why do you mention that?

Comment: Probably because treating `<$x>` different from `<$x >` or `< $x >` is a reason to get your knickers in a knot.

Comment: @nwellnhof, You appear to have only read half of my sentence, because I specifically said that's not a reason to your knickers in a not since it happens all the time. `/$x/` is different than `/$x /`. `"$x"` is different than `"$x "`. etc

Comment: But `m{}` and `qq{}` are *quote-like* operators, so it's obvious that whitespace is significant. The problem with the diamond operator is that it's used as a shortcut for both `glob` and `readline` and that it should at least allow leading or trailing whitespace in the `readline` case. Do you really want to argue that this isn't a huge design mistake?

Comment: @nwellnhof, Yes, I will indeed argue that allowing trailing blanks in the glob case is NOT a huge design mistake. There is a huge design mistake, but it's allowing `<>` to take a sublanguage instead of just an expression to pass to `readline`.